# Lumen and MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, laravel, lumen

Is it somehow possible to include the mongodb connection settings into a lumen framework. As from what I saw the config/database.php is loaded internally in the lumen package. Is there a way to extend it somehow to include the mongodb connection settings?

Comment: Have you heard of [Moloquent](http://jenssegers.be/blog/48/combining-laravel-and-mongodb)? The *develop* branch on the Github [repository](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/blob/develop/composer.json) targets L5 so presumably **Lumen** also. Why not give a try to it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

We're actually using Lumen, Laravel, Mongo, and MySQL in one giant project so I can help you through this one. Assuming you want to use MongoDB with eloquent instead of with the raw MongoClient. You can find the library I'm using from jenssegers [here](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb).

### Install MongoDB Extension

Firstly you'll need to install the dependencies for PHP to interact with mongo. The specifics for installing the mongo extension can be found on the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php).

After that you'll have to edit the php.ini files for the platforms (apache/cli/nginx) to load the extension. I added the following before *Module Settings*

```
extension=mongo.so
```

It goes without saying you need to restart apache/nginx after changing the configuration.

### Configuring Lumen

In your root lumen folder you can add it to your requirements with the following command.

```
composer require jenssegers/mongodb
```

From there you'll need to also load the MongodbServiceProvider **before** Facades or Eloquent is initialized.

```
$app->register(Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider::class);

$app->withFacades();

$app->withEloquent();
```

For simplicity of organizing configuration I also created a config folder and a database.php config file. Since Lumen doesn't try to autoload or search this directory we have to tell it to load this config. I put the following line right before the loading the application routes.

```
$app->configure('database');
```

In database.php the mongodb driver requires a specific structure. I've included mysql in here as I use both, but if you're using mongo exclusively you can change default to mongodb and remove the mysql config.

```
<?php

    return  [
        'default' => 'mysql',
    
        'connections' => [
            'mysql' => [
                'driver'    => 'mysql',
                'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
                'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
                'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
                'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                'prefix'    => '',
                'strict'    => false,
            ],
    
            'mongodb' => array(
                'driver'   => 'mongodb',
                'host'     => env('MONGODB_HOST', 'localhost'),
                'port'     => env('MONGODB_PORT', 27017),
                'username' => env('MONGODB_USERNAME', ''),
                'password' => env('MONGODB_PASSWORD', ''),
                'database' => env('MONGODB_DATABASE', ''),
                'options' => array(
                    'db' => env('MONGODB_AUTHDATABASE', '') //Sets the auth DB
                )
            ),
    
        ],
    ];
```

With the configuration out of the way you can now create a model, as of writing this to create a model for mongo (check the github page) you can use the following as a base. You can ignore the $connection variable if mongo is your default driver.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;

class Example extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'example';
    protected $primaryKey = '_id';
}
```

There you go, you should be able to interact with mongo normally, for the specifics of the driver check out the github page for documentation on it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! It works! I almost had it done by this point, perhaps I've missed something. Brilliant answer! Thank you!

Comment: @user743777 Glad to help!

Comment: I got a white screen with a status code of 200 after I followed this, And when I debug the $app instance in my app, I see that there is no db property set. What should I change there ? The app dies after Jennsengers Mongo registration because of the missing db in the app.

Comment: Warning: `jenssegers/mongodb` MongoDB Driver for Eloquent is unstable and unmaintained.

Comment: I agree with mate64 here. don't use `jenssegers/mongodb`. use official `mongo-php-library`. it has PHP7 support also

Answer (score 10):

#### 2016 (Update)

There is now a simple [Doctrine MongoDB ODM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/mongodb-odm.html) **Provider** for the [Lumen PHP framework](https://lumen.laravel.com/).

```
composer require nordsoftware/lumen-doctrine-mongodb-odm
```

[GitHub Source Code](https://github.com/nordsoftware/lumen-doctrine-mongodb-odm)

---

**Warning**

`jenssegers/mongodb` is a **Driver** sitting on top of [Illumante's Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent).

Think of it: [Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) is **primary made for SQL**. And let's cut with the chase: The package is the reinvention of the wheel - as a side effect, major [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb) features are not supported. Besides that, the package is unstable and unmaintained.

Be aware, `jenssegers/mongodb` will vent your anger and frustration:

[image: jenssegers/mongodb exploding issues and pr's]

Comment: 2019 update . Jenssegers has 110 issues and 4.9k stars, while nordsoftware has 4 issues and 16 stars ....

Comment: One would expect Object oriented way to handle nosql documents. jenssegers/mongodb is not suitable for large projects and sophisticated document schemas where you would want to create documents and embedded documents. doctrine-odm is far more better than this. However, someone needs to create a dedicated package for mongodb that fits properly in the laravel ecosystem

Answer (score -1):

Just a change in [@Sieabah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2593848/sieabah) user:
instead: `extension=mongo.so`
choose: `extension=mongodb.so`

Comment: Believe it depends on the PHP version, the official mongo installation is http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php