# Lumen Migration Schema for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, lumen

I installed Jenssegers MongoDB follow this
[Lumen and MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547827/lumen-and-mongodb?answertab=votes#tab-top) answer and it work.

However, I tried to create a new collection using migration schema follow the example (https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#schema) and it not work. My function up:

```
Schema::create('users', function($collection)
    {
        $collection->index('name');
        $collection->unique('email');
    });
```

I got an error message:

> [MongoException] Collection name cannot be empty

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

very late but you can try

```
/** Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{        
    Schema::connection($this->connection)
    ->table('actions', function (Blueprint $collection) 
    {
        $collection->index('name');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::connection($this->connection)
    ->table('actions', function (Blueprint $collection) 
    {
        $collection->drop();
    });
}
```

Src: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/859