# How can we use mongo queries in lumen?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5, lumen

Currently I am using

```
public function checkExist($login, $email) 
{
    return $this->where('login', $login)
        ->whereIN('email', $email)
        ->count();
}
```

Now we want to change our whole db operations with mongoDB. So, how many steps we need to take and how can we write basic ddl and dml operations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lumen and MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547827/lumen-and-mongodb)

Answer (score 1):

You guys are not the first to use Lumen with MongoDB. You even can continue using **Eloquent ORM for creating your queries**. There are some implementations on Github which are providing a solution to this.

Here is one way to do it (this solution is provided by https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-mongodb-with-your-lumen-api-e13f36fa0aa6, check the link for more details):

1) Install https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb with composer

2) Register the service provider in bootstrap/app.php:

```
$app->register(Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider::class);
$app->withEloquent();
```

3) Create config/database.php and add PHP:

```
return [
    'default' => 'mongodb',
    'connections' => [
        'mongodb' => [ 
            'driver' => ‘mongodb',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', 27017),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'options' => [
                'database' => 'admin' // sets the authentication database required by mongo 3
            ]
        ],
    ],
    ‘migrations’ => ‘migrations’,
];
```

4) Now you can use MongoDB within your .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
DB_HOST=<dbHost>
DB_PORT=27017
DB_DATABASE=<dbName>
DB_USERNAME=<dbUser>
DB_PASSWORD=<dbUserPassword>
```

An alternative solution probably would be the Moloquent library: https://github.com/moloquent/moloquent